# Why is this Destructuring assignment usage not working?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Im trying to learn Destructuring assignments and was wandering why is this way of using it is not working:

```js
let options = [...document.querySelectorAll("#listado option:checked")].map((el, { value}) => value)
console.log(options)
```

```html
<select id="listado" size="5" multiple>
  <option value="Leer" id="aficion-leer">Leer</option>
  <option value="Programar" id="aficion-programar" selected>Programar</option>
  <option value="Cine" id="aficion-cine">Cine</option>
  <option value="Deporte" id="aficion-deporte" selected>Deporte</option>
</select>
```

And without it is working:

```
.map(el => el.value)
```

Comment: The *second parameter* to the `.map()` callback is the index of the index of the item. You're trying to destructure a number and get its `value` property which doesn't exist. The correct syntax is `.map(({value}) => value)` to destructure the first parameter.

Comment: There, I closed it myself, its is so not useful to anybody jugged by close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructure the *item being iterated over* - which is the first parameter, not the second. (The second is the index being iterated over, which is a number.)

```js
let options = [...document.querySelectorAll("#listado option:checked")].map(({ value }) => value)
console.log(options)
```

```html
<select id="listado" size="5" multiple>
  <option value="Leer" id="aficion-leer">Leer</option>
  <option value="Programar" id="aficion-programar" selected>Programar</option>
  <option value="Cine" id="aficion-cine">Cine</option>
  <option value="Deporte" id="aficion-deporte" selected>Deporte</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible to deconstruct it something a long lines of this: `let options {value} = [...document.querySelectorAll("#listado option:checked")].map(el => el)` I think i seen something like this somewhere but can get it to work. (posible i seen it in case of the different object example.)

Comment: The extra `.map` does nothing there. You can't both destructure a property (like `value`) *and* retain the original object in any reasonable fashion - do it on separate lines instead.

Comment: Can you please show me, I tried to it like: `let options = [...document.querySelectorAll("#listado option:checked")]; let result, {value}   =  options` and more of obviously wrong ways.

Comment: `const [option] = document.queryS(...); const { value } = option;`? though if you only want a single one, it'd make more sense to use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`

Comment: I tried that, but im getting the whole elements. Not there's values. Goal is to deconstruct values after. If possible.

Comment: Do you want a single element, or multiple elements? Do you need just the value from the element(s), or do you need values from each?

Comment: @ikiK destructuring is an alternative way of getting *variables*. If you want to change a whole array, that's the job typically given to `.map()`. If you want to take one or several items from an array (or iterable), you can use array destructuring. If you want to take one (or several) properties of a single object, you can use object destructuring. Each of those will give you one *variable* per thing you've destructured.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Multiple elements, there's values. So after creating an array of elements,  deconstruct the values alone.

Comment: I think i am aware of everything you said. And i know hot get all I need, just not using destructuring method in for example above snippet, even in 2step after getting array of elements.  @VLAZ I would like to know a way of getting same result, an array of values. I may be missing some basic logic that is blocking me to understand this fully.

Comment: Btw this is only for my understanding and learning so feel free to skip explaining if you see im out of touch with basic logic about this...

Comment: @ikiK Simply put, you cannot. Again, destructuring gives you *one* variable per thing you destructure. `{value} = arr` will try to take the `value` property of the array, it's equivalent to `value = arr.value`. It will not process the whole array and give you the `value` property of each item. If you cannot do a normal assignment into a variable, then you cannot destructure it.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. @VLAZ Thanks!